# New/Existing LoadRunner script cannot be opened in Virtual User Generator

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I am a newbie to **LoadRunner** tool, Here I downloaded LoadRunner_2020_Community_Edition for learning purpose. Using **Virtual User Generator** I tried to open the script but it is throwing below error,

[image]

And by default when my system started to open, It throws Unhanded exception error

[image]

Is there any solution to open the test script in **Virtual User Generator** ? Literally it stops me from learning purpose to improve my technical skills for my better career, So please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't worry we are here for you. Can you try installing again? It looks like an installation error. Also can you write which operating system you are using and if you have administrator permissions when installing. Thanks.

Comment: @Buzzy It works after re-installation, Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

1) Does the installation work smoothly?

2) Please try to run this command from cmd :
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\RegSvr32.exe 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\LoadRunner\bin\scriptutils.dll"
 (you should get a popup of succeeded )

3) if after #2 you still launch VuGen and get this error, 
   please send us an email from the menu : help -> send us your feedback

and attach 2 logfiles from %temp% folder :
HP.LR.VuGen.log
LoadRunner.log

Regards,
Oren